# Add an extra color in wes_palette

Tags: r, colors

I know this is a little rookie, but I've created a `wes_palette` like this:

```
rnq<-wesanderson::wes_palette("Zissou", 5, "discrete")
```

to plot an interval of values from 0 to 4.

But I have a single value in my data that is 9, and I would like to disclose it, using, for example, black.

Im using `spplot`:

```
rng = seq(0, 4, length=5)
rnq<-wesanderson::wes_palette("Zissou", 5, "discrete")
scale = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(), 
             offset = c(-900000,-1100000), 
             scale = 300000, fill=c("transparent","black"))
text1 = list("sp.text", c(-900000,-1150000), "0")
text2 = list("sp.text", c(-550000,-1150000), "300 Km")
text4<-list("sp.text", c( -730000, -1270000), cex=0.6, "Projection: EPSG 102003")
arrow = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), 
             offset = c(-900000, -400000), scale = 200000)
spplot(spdf_img, "re1", col = "white", at = rng, 
       col.regions = rnq,
       colorkey = list(
         space = "bottom", labels=list(
           at=round(rng, 1))),
       sp.layout=list(scale, text1, text2, text4, arrow),
       par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = NA)))
```

Mainly, I don't know how to define my `interval("rnq"`), plus the color ramp and then the cuts (`at` argument in `spplot`) to change the value 9 to black.

The map is this: 
[gh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frzvb.png)

And the white polygon is the one I need to change the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I managed to fix it, with more or less your code.

```
rng = c(seq(0, 4, length=5), 9)
rnq = c("#3B9AB2", "#78B7C5", "#EBCC2A", "darkorange1", "#F21A00")
```

Anyway, Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the value 9 and the color black at your current rng and rnq:

```
rng <- c(rng,9)
rnq <- c(rnq,"black")
```

Then your code should work.